# Invalid option in build() call: "incremental"

Tags: node.js, serverless

I am making a small project using serverless, but when I try to run it in the terminal I get this error:

[image]

Repository:https://github.com/IagoAndrade16/Generate-certificates

Can anyone help me? I've searched the internet for this error but I can't find anything about

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in esbuild serverless.

ESBUILD has a breaking change. You need to downgrade your esbuild to .16

Details here... https://github.com/floydspace/serverless-esbuild/issues/427